# Правильная реализация однопоточного синглтона в C++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-проектирования

Как я реализовал:

```
#pragma once
class Singletone {
private: 
Singletone(): instance(nullptr) {}
Singletone(const Singletone&);
const Singletone& operator=(const Singletone&);
static Singletone * instance;
~Singletone() { delete instance; }
public:

  static const Singletone& getInstance();

}
```

singletone.cpp:

```
#include "Singletone.h"
Singletone* Singletone::instance = nullptr;
const Singletone& Singletone::getInstance() {
     if(instance==nullptr)
           instance = new Singletone();
    return *instance;
}
```

Скажите, насколько правильна такая реализация?
Например, я не могу вернуть ссылку т.к. запрещен конструктор копирования (который должен быть запрещен, верно?)
Что тогда делать, возвращать указатель на объект, или?...
И какой лучший способ создания однопоточного синглтона в C++?

Comment: > Например, я не могу вернуть ссылку
> т.к. запрещен конструктор копирования
> (который должен быть запрещен, верно?)

при создании ссылок и указателей конструктор ненужен (объект ведь не создаётся)
подробнее о возврате ссылок 

[Как работает возврат ссылки? ][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/178009#180400

Comment: Еще могу порекомендовать чтение https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.lang.c++.moderated/qHDCU73cEFc (большей частью из-за комментариев по теме).

Comment: А мне одному кажется, что строка
~Singletone() { delete instance; }
вызовет UB?
Если есть только один объект instance, зачем при его удалении. пытаться удалить его еще раз?

Comment: Я наверное что-то не понимаю. В данном случае строка `delete instance` вызовет деструктор `~Singletone()`, который опять выполнит строку `delete instance`, которая опят вызовет деструктор и так далее. Или я что-то упускаю?

Comment: @nnesterov Сейчас еще раз прочитал код топикстартера и деструктор `~Singletone()` вообще не будет вызван никогда, поскольку статическим членом класса является `raw` указатель. Поэтому того, о чем вы говорите, не произойдет, но деструктор, очевидно, бессмысленен. Извините, что ввел в заблуждение предыдущим комментарием `:)`

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать: а если

    delete &Singletone::getInstance();

?

---
Ах да, деструктор приватный же, не выйдет.

Comment: Статические члены класса не могут инициализироваться в списке инициализации конструктора.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.

```
if(instance==nullptr)
       instance = new Singletone();
```

А с чего Вы решили, что неинициализированный указатель будет равен `nullptr` ?

2.

> Например, я не могу вернуть ссылку т.к. запрещен конструктор копирования (который должен быть запрещен, верно?)

А какая связь между возвращаемой ссылкой и конструктором копирования?

Comment: mikillskeg, посмотрите пожалуйста еще раз мой вопрос, я там добавил что в .cpp instance инициализируется nullptr'ом.
2. оно не может сконструировть объект при его возвращении.

Comment: А как и где будет инициироваться указатель, если он объявлен как private? А если его сделать public, то последнее будет хуже первого.

Лучше прислушайтесь к ответу @KoVadim'а и изучите синглтон Мейерса. Он похож на Ваше решение, но не совсем. Удачи.

Comment: Во-первых, указатель обявлен как `static`, т.е. он гарантированно будет изначально `nullptr`. Во-вторых, он даже явно инициализирован.

Answer (score 6):

Есть же классические реализации синглтонов, почему не воспользоваться? Заодно узнаете типовые ошибки:

- [Три возраста паттерна Singleton](http://habrahabr.ru/post/147373/)
- [Синглтон и время жизни объекта](http://habrahabr.ru/post/118368/)

Comment: спасибо   
.

Answer (score 4):

У вас лишний деструктор. Фактически, вы не должны никому разрешать уничтожить синглтон. Деструктор нужно оставить приватным, но пустым.

Других проблем в однопоточном случае не вижу.

Для запрета конструктора копирования, оператора присваивания и деструктора можно воспользоваться конструкцией `= delete`, если ваш компилятор поддерживает C++11. Но это вопрос вкуса.

Ссылку вы вернуть можете потому, что ссылка на объект представляет *тот же самый* объект, копирования не происходит.

ЗЫ: на английском вроде бы Singleton, без "e".

ЗЗЫ: да, у вас ещё нету точки с запятой после объявления класса.

ЗЗЗЫ: А синглтон Майерса таки гораздо изящнее.